# RSpec in Rails: How to skip a before_filter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, separation-of-concerns, before-filter

I am trying to test my controller and maintain separation of concerns.

**The first concern is "Who is able to execute which action?"**
I am using *authlogic* for authentication and *[be9's acl9](http://github.com/be9/acl9)* for authorization. But this should not matter, all my authorization concerns are handled in a `before_filter`. I am testing such a `before_filter` by something similar to this:

```
describe SomeModelsController, "GET to index (authorization)" do
  before(:each) do
    @siteadmin = mock_model(User)
    @siteadmin.stub!(:has_role?).with("siteadmin", nil).and_return(true)
  end

  it "should grant access to a siteadmin" do
    controller.should_receive(:current_user).at_least(:once).and_return(@siteadmin)
    get :index
    response.should be_success
  end
end
```

This spec is working just fine!

**Now, the second concern is "Does the action do what it is supposed to do?"**
This does not involve checking authorization. The best/cleanest solution would be skipping that `before_filter` all together and just do something like:

```
describe SomeModelsController, "GET to index (functional)" do
  it "should find all Models" do
    Model.should_receive(:find).with(:all)
  end
end
```

Without having to worry about which user with which role has to logged in first. Right now I solved it like that:

```
describe SomeModelsController, "GET to index (functional)" do
  before(:each) do
    @siteadmin = mock_model(User)
    @siteadmin.stub!(:has_role?).with("siteadmin", nil).and_return(true)
    controller.stub!(:current_user).and_return(@siteadmin)
   end
  
  it "should find all Models" do
    Model.should_receive(:find).with(:all)
  end
end
```

If I now decided that my siteadmin does not have the right to access the index action anymore, it would not only break one spec - namely the spec that HAS to break in such a case - but also the totally unrelated second spec.

I know this is basically a minor issue, but it would be nice if somebody could come up with an (elegant) solution!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

To skip the before filter:

```
controller.class.skip_before_filter :name_of_method_used_as_before_filter
```

The one caveat ([mentioned the docs](http://ap.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html#M000132)) is that this will only work for method-reference filters, not procs.

Alternatively, you could stub `current_user.has_role?`

```
describe SomeModelsController, "GET to index (functional)" do
  before(:each) do
    controller.current_user.stub!(:has_role?).and_return(true)
  end

  it "should find all Models" do
    Model.should_receive(:find).with(:all)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't think about this one.
If there's not way to skip the before_filter, this might be the best solution.

Comment: Nice, skipping the before filter works. The only downside is that acl9 installs a nameless lambda filter per default, so I have to force the creation of a named before_filter.

Comment: This didn't really work for me (rails 3.2.3). More up to date help can be found here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Controllers-and-Views-tests-with-Rails-3-(and-rspec)

Comment: beware that stubbing controller.class will affect all other instances of that class throughout your test suite.

Comment: Nowadays you'll likely write it as `described_class.skip_before_action :my_callback_method`

Comment: @mkirk We had this problem in the test suite of a production app. (Tests randomly failing because a skip_before_action affected tests running **after** the test calling the skip). This lost hours of developer time. I would recommend a stub instead.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I had to solve this just recently. This will only work for Rails 3.1, for earlier versions you should replace `_process_action_callbacks` with `filter_chain` (untested)

You can simply delete a matching Proc from the filter chain like so (Test::Unit example):

```
class RandomControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  def setup
    @controller.class._process_action_callbacks.each do |f|
      @controller.class._process_action_callbacks.delete(f) if f.raw_filter.to_s.match(/**<match for your proc>**/)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score -9):

How about just not doing a GET request?
Try calling the controller method by itself.

```
controller.index
```